# Periscope login via Twitter

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm trying log in Periscope via Twitter. I use Twiter4j library. So, what I'm do:

Firstly, I use my Twitter app, which I create in apps.twitter.com and try to log in Twitter with pin code. It is OK. Then I use access token key and secret and do POST request to Periscope with getted data and get response:

> Unauthorized (401)

I don't know why it happens.

Where I can get the Periscope oauth_token and secret token?

Comment: Be more specific. How do you use your access token

Comment: just send the requests with my app tokens